# mod_rewrite interaction between two .htaccess files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`.htaccess` file located in web root `/`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^product.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.product.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^product.com.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.product.com.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.company.com/product/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^company.com.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.company.com.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^companyalternate.com.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.companyalternate.com.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^company.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.company.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

`.htaccess` file located in `/product/blog/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /product/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?article=$1
```

As far as I can tell, URL rewriting is working as expected, until I enter something like:

`company.com.au/product/blog/test-article`

In this case, the resulting url appears exactly as entered, however the expected content is retrieved from the `/product/blog/index.php` script.  So the `/product/blog/.htaccess` is being processed, but it seems the `/.htaccess` is not?

I would expect the above URL to be redirected to:

`https://www.company.com/product/blog/index.php?article=test-article`

And to appear as:

`https://www.company.com/product/blog/test-article`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: But you really need two files? Can't you just put the `RewriteRule (.*) /product/blog/index.php?article=$1` on your file?

Comment: I don't *need* two files, certainly not.  However I am still wondering why it does not work, as it is.  Does Apache only process a single htaccess file, then stop?

Comment: As far as I know, Apache will use the closest .htaccess file to the requested directory. Maybe using just one (root) will do the trick. BTW, here is Apache docs on rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent this except deleting the /folder/.htaccess. This is because when you request /folder/foobar server first reads the /folder/.htaccess and if it doesnt exist then the root htaccess is called.

Comment: @khargoosh: What is your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhava Apache 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already been mentioned in comments/answer that Apache .htaccess is per-directory directive. Apache only uses closest/nearest .htaccess so in your case it is **only using `/product/blog/.htaccess` and ignoring `/.htaccess`**:

You can use this directive at top of your `/product/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

This will make rules from the **parent scope** are **applied before** rules specified in the **child scope**.

[Here is Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official documentation,

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up. Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those, in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the main server configuration file itself.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html#how

I'm guessing your question is why it's not being 301 redirected.

Without looking too much into it, I'm going to say that it has to be do with content already being served. If content has already been served, the 301 header probably can't be set.